# How do I debug jQuery File Upload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload

I'm using blueimp's [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). On my localhost I'm able to upload files without difficulty, but on my server it's a different story. Some files have loaded successfully, but others fail very quickly. For example, one file goes to 2%, back to 0% back to 2%, pauses, then silently fails.

My questions are:

1. What are the obvious things to check that could cause this failure?
2. What can I do to help debug the failure (perhaps by writing something to the console?)

I'm testing with a 150Mb file. PHP.ini has the following:

```
post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 256M
max_input_time = 6000
memory_limit = 128M
max_execution_time = 2700 ; Just in case! I'd prefer to change this back.
```

Comment: Check if you can upload smaller files.

Comment: @Bala.C - I'm going some more extensive testing, but upload speeds are SLOOOOW which means testing takes a long time. I have successfully uploaded files of 75Mb, which takes about 20 minutes. The 150Mb file fails within 2 minutes.

Comment: I found the problem for this specific issue. I'm using Cloudflare, which as a [maximum file upload of 100Mb](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169776-What-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-upload-through-CloudFlare-).

I'm still interested in knowing how to write to the console to debug future issues, though.